# how to refresh angularjs ui-calendar after data fetched from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

below code are sample code of my new application using angularjs.I integrated ui-calendar and done some customization in it.Iam trying to fetch data from server and display in ui-calendar.Data is fetching using angularjs http request but calendar is not displaying any data in it.when I remove that http request success call dummy data is working properly.in below code loaddata iam calling inside success call,there I keep eventsource to add data in calendar.but no data is displaying.how do i use angular http request to put data in ui-calendar.Please,thanks in advance,one more thing that is I am using fullcalendar

```
$scope.eventSources2 = [];
if ($rootScope.checkConnection()) {
    apiFactory.getData()
        .success(function(res) {
            LoadData(res.data); // <- this is function which is calling to display data in calendar
            console.log(res);
        })
        .error(function(e){
            console.log('check error log');
            console.log(e);
        });
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your ui-calendar in your html, there should be a ng-model.
You should update in your LoadData function, that variable and Angular will do the trick.

Comment: <div  class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources2" calendar="myCalendar3" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>

Comment: $scope.eventSources2 = [newValue]; value this eventsource2 also showing when iam using {{}} in view

Comment: have you tried removing and adding again all eventSources?

Answer (score 0):

uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar3'].fullCalendar('addEventSource',$scope.calEventsExt); here mycalendar3 is

hope this answer will help those who is also struggling on this...

Comment: <div   class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources2" calendar="myCalendar3" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>